# Skip validations for nested attributes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm currently working with nested forms/fields_for and I was wondering if there was an easy way to skip validations for nested attributes?

Can I maybe squeeze a object.nested_object.save(:validate => false) in somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need do your save in two part. The first save about the parent saving and second part about nested

If you use an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on this nested field

```
def create
  nested_params = params[:object].delete(:nested_attributes)
  if object = Object.create(params[:object]) && 
    object.update_attributes(nested_params, :validate => false)
    redirect_to object_url(object)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

**Update with comment from Cojones :**

If you don't use this option you need assign directly the nested_attribute like explain on comment :

```
def create
  nested_params = params[:object].delete(:nested_attributes)
  if object = Object.create(params[:object]) && 
    object.nested_object.update_attributes(nested_params, :validate => false)
    redirect_to object_url(object)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Please see comment for more information.

Comment: I tried to put this into practice but it failed: undefined method `{"user_id"=>... Are you sure you want to call 'update_attribute'? Because that method expects the name of the attribute as first parameter according to the API.

Comment: Yes it's a typo issue, it's `update_attributes` I fix it on my answer

Comment: `object.update_attributes(nested_params, :validate => false)` also doesn't work because it tries to assign the attributes of the nested object to the object itself. `object.nested_object.update_attributes(nested_params, :validate => false)` did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Depend if you use the accept_attributes_nested or not. I update my answer with this information

Comment: I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and it doesn't work without calling the update_attributes on the nested object.

Comment: I ran into another problem: When the nested object also have nested objects, it doesn't skip validation for them. This is a bit annoying cause I can't really use it now :(

Comment: Yes the method is not recursive

Comment: Do you know a way to make it skip validation for all nested objects? I've been trying around for almost to hours now and couldn't find a clean way.

Comment: I don't think there are valid solution. Sorry

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll have to do workaround for that. Thanks anyway!