# Rails 3.0 Skip validations for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-attributes

I need to be able to save a record without running validations on itself or its nested attributes. I'm stuck in Rails 3.0, and I cannot update to a newer version.

I have a report, each report has many responses (answers to questions). The responses are nested in the report form.

There are two ways the user should be able to save the report: Submit for review, where all validations are run, and Save And Finish Later, where no validations are run for the report or the nested responses. This needs to work for both create and update actions.

I am currently trying to use conditional validations. This works for update but not create. The problem is this line:

```
validate :has_answer_if_required, :if => Proc.new { |response| !response.report.finish_later? }
```

The report doesn't exist yet, so active record can't find this responses's report. That's where it crashes.

There are a lot some suggested solutions for this problem, but I couldn't get them working in Rails 3.0. update_attributes(attributes, :validate => false), for instance, is not available in Rails 3.0.

So, how do I skip the validations in the nested attributes?

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses, :order => "created_at asc", :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses
  ...
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
  validates_associated  :report

  validate :has_answer_if_required, :if => Proc.new { |response| !response.report.finish_later? }
  validate :correct_answer_or_comment, :if => Proc.new { |response| !response.report.finish_later? }
end

class ReportsController < BaseController

  def update
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    @report.attributes = params[:report]

    if params[:finish_later].nil?
      @report.update_attribute(:finish_later, false)
      if @report.save!
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      render :template => "reports/edit"
    end
    else
      @report.finish_later = true
      @report.save(:validate => false)
      redirect_to :action => :index
    end
  end

  def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])
    if params[:finish_later].nil?
      @report.finish_later = false
      if @report.save!
        redirect_to :action => :index
      else
        render :template => "reports/edit"
      end
    else
      @report.finish_later = true
      @report.save!(:validate => false)
      redirect_to :action => :index
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529766/skip-validations-for-nested-attributes-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work with nested attributes, though I think it should... but give ValidationSkipper a try:

https://github.com/npearson72/validation_skipper

Just make sure you call `skip_validation_for` on the object you want to skip. Since nested attributes pass behavior to their children, you might be able to call this method directly on the parent object. Give it a try.