# Validations with accept_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes, one-to-one

I'm having issues with some code of my rails app, imagine the follow scenario:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :participant, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :username

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant
end
```

**participant.rb**

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :phone_number
end
```

The problem happens when I run `valid?` method

```
user = User.first
user.valid?
#=> true
```

At this point user validations are ok (it's running only the validations from User model), but if for some reason the association with participant is loaded, then `valid?` method's gonna run the validations from **User** and from **Participant** which IMHO is wrong since `user` is an instance of User model

```
user.participant  
Participant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]  
 => #<Participant id: 1, user_id: 1, phone_number: "", created_at: "2015-01-13 18:15:34", updated_at: "2015-01-13 18:48:27">
user.valid?  
#=>false
user.errors.full_messages  
#=> ["Participant phone number can't be blank"]
```

I would agree with this validation if I were updating something in participant model but I'm not. Is this a bug or there is any way that I could skip the associated validations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Rails nested attributes pass behavior to the parents children.  So **if you call .valid? on the parent it will check validations on all the children**.  This is the intended structure and is this way to ensure that the associated model is valid, because you asked it to be.

The question I have for you is why would you have a validation on your Participant model for the phone_number attribute if you want to skip that validation?  **You either need to remove the validation for phone_number or ensure that a phone_number is present.**  I think you need to re-assess the structure of your model's and validations with this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, models suppose to have all the businnes logic isolated, I have the validation of the phone_number because is the way as the Participant model should work (that was an example though, I have more validations in my real model). I understand what you're saying but it seems a little bit akward to me since I'm not modifying anything in the participant model, maybe there's another way to do this somehow.

Comment: Hi Richard, Models do have their logic isolated to that particular Model, this is true.  But when you nest the Participant Model under the User Model you are in fact performing an operation on both Models and thus calling the validations on both.  Here is another example of how the nested associations work: When you perform User.save it would perform .save on the associated Participant model to save the attributes for the nested Model.  The same logic applies to running .valid? it will run .valid? on both the parent and the nested children, because that is what is expected when nesting models.

Comment: Correct, but the thing is that the `valid?` method is going to run in both models (`User` and `Participant`) only if the relationship (used in the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`) is loaded.

Comment: in your example above the User (id => 1) you are testing with has an associated Participant (participant_id => 1) so and you loaded it therefore it loads the Participant model validations for that User when you run user.valid? and it fails validation because the associated participant does not have a valid phone_number.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this thread... maybe it can be of use to you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529766/skip-validations-for-nested-attributes-in-rails-3